# Why doesn't this proof work? (Zero times infinity equals zero)

Tags: proof-verification, infinity

Say we are trying to prove 
$$
0\cdot n = 0
$$
By mathematical induction, we start with a base case of n = 1
$$
0\cdot 1 = 0
$$
So now we assume our original formula is true, and try to prove a case for $n+1$.
$$
0\cdot (n+1) = 0\cdot n + 0\cdot 1 = 0
$$
Why can't we take the limit as n approaches infinity?

This would tell us that infinity times zero is equal to zero.

Comment: If this did work, you could also use it to prove that infinity was a finite number: 0 is a finite number, and if $n$ is finite, then $n+1$ is finite, therefore…

Comment: You can indeed take limit as $n\to\infty$. You get the valid equation $\lim_{n\to\infty}(0(n))=0$. The step that is problematic is then to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}0(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0\lim_{n\to\infty}n$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/98093/

Answer (score 6):

Mathematical induction in the way you used it allows you to prove that a statement is true for all *natural numbers* (positive integers). Infinity is not a natural number, so your proof doesn't apply to infinity.

What you've shown is that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$0 \cdot n = 0$$