# Why is this 'Proof' by induction not valid?

Tags: summation, induction, fake-proofs

I am trying to understand why induction is valid. For instance why would this 'proof' not be valid under the principle of proof by induction ? :

> 

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \lt \infty$$ because using induction on the statement 
$$S(n) =  \sum_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \lt \infty$$
- "$S(1) < \infty$ is true and "$S(n) < \infty$" implies "$S(n+1) < \infty$" since $S(n+1)  \lt S(n) + \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Read the principle of mathematical induction again. The conclusion  only says $P(n)$ is true for every integer $n$, which is very different from $P(\infty)$ being true.

Comment: This is one of my favourite mathematical errors. A thing and its limit need not have anything in common. You can build a hollow house out of solid bricks.

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate, but strongly related [Why doesn't induction extend to infinity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/98093/18880).

Comment: The question, and in particular the final line, is (also) confused about whether $S(n)$ designates a value or a proposition.

Comment: You also need to make very sure that you're not treating infinity like a number just because it is on the right of an inequality. By "the infinite sum is less than infinity" we are not actually comparing two numbers. This is just a convenient shorthand for *there exists a number b (for "bound") such that every finite sum is less than b*.

Comment: This is similar to the problem that many have with $0.999\cdots=1$; notice that for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 9 {10^{k+1}}<1$, but $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac 9 {10^{k+1}}=1$

Comment: A simple example may be helpful. $n<\infty$ for any $n<\infty$, but we cannot say that this implies that $n<\infty$ for $n=\infty$.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

With induction, you can only prove $S(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$. However, even though $S(n)$ is true for arbitrarily large $n$, the statement "$S(\infty)$" does not follow from induction because $\infty$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: Also the statement $S(n)$ is meaningless for finite $n$; $<\infty$ does not say anything at all about a finite sum of real numbers.

Comment: It's not meaningless, it's just TRUE.

Comment: @R..: “$<\infty$ ” does not say anything in any notation with which I am familiar. More pertinent is that the definition of $ S(\infty) $ is not the same as the definition of $ S(n) $ for $ n \in \mathbb N $. And in the latter case, of course, as Tom Church says, $S(n)$ **is** true.

Answer (score 56):

The same proof shows that the set of all positive integers is finite:

\begin{align}
& \{1\} \text{ is finite.} \\
& \{1,2\} \text{ is finite.} \\
& \{1,2,3\} \text{ is finite.} \\
& \{1,2,3,4\} \text{ is finite.} \\
& \qquad \vdots \\
& \text{and so on.} \\
\text{Therefore } & \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\} \text{ is finite.}
\end{align}

Comment: This is a good start of an answer but I think you need to elaborate a little more on why it doesn't work.

Comment: This still creeps me out because of the time when I was stupid enough to try to reason with an anti set theory crank.

Comment: I see what you're going for, but your claim doesn't match your proof. You have shown through induction that for n > 0, {1, ..., n} has a cardinality of n.

Comment: @Kjata30 : I'm not following you. The idea is that if you add one more element to a finite set, you get a finite set; therefore every initial segment of the set of all positive integers is finite.

Answer (score 25):

By induction you have proved that for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 k$ is finite, which is true. This is not the same as proving that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac 1 k$ is finite...

Answer (score 17):

I would add to the other comments that when you take the limit $<$ changes into $\le$. So by taking the limit you would get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\le\infty$, which is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers make the valid point that you can only deduce $( \forall n \in \mathbb N :P(n) )$ by induction, but not $ P(\infty) $ (though see footnote<sup>1</sup>). There is, however, another problem in your case:

> Your “$ P $” does not have the same meaning in “$ P(n)$” (where $ n\in \mathbb N $) as it does in “$ P(\infty) $”.

This is confusing, as the notation is the same, but an infinite sum is defined as a limit while a finite sum is defined inductively. Because of this, induction tells us nothing about $ P(\infty) $.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can sometimes deduce $P(\omega)$ when using [transfinite induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction), but that is a different technique and a different story.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people are talking about the meaning of $P(\infty)$, which I believe is something of a red herring: usually the symbol $\infty$ is a *notational convenience*, and has no meaning as a *formal object*.

In particular:

- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ means $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m x_n$, where again, the limit towards $\infty$ has a precise mathematical meaning not involving the symbol $\infty$.
- $x<\infty$ simply means that there is some $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x<C$. Alternately, for an increasing sequence $x_n$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n<\infty$ means that there is a $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n<C$ *for every $n$*.

Now if you try to prove that there is some $C$ such that for every $m$, $\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n}<C$, you'll run into trouble: certainly there is some such $C$ for each $m$, but there is no $C$ that works *uniformly for every $m$*. Indeed, if $x<C$, then $x+\frac{1}{m}$ could very well be above $C$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ is the same as any other limit if you consider $\infty$ as an element in the one-point compactification of ${\bf N}$. You can do very similar things with nets. Personally, I think when we have a fixed sequence under consideration, it is enough to write $\lim_n$ without using the symbol $\infty$.

Comment: The same is true about $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n<\infty$ -- you just need to consider ${\bf R}$ as a subset of its two-point compactification. If you don't, $x<\infty$ is completely meaningless: any number is less than infinity.

Comment: It's true that $\infty$ *can* be given meaning with enough (not that much) work, in a similar way that $dy/dx$ can be seen as an actual fraction in certain settings. I'm not sure that introducing limits in the context of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ is the right pedagogical move though.