# Find the $x^2$ coefficient by induction of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

In one of Wikipedia's proofs of the solution to the Basel problem, they state that the $x^2$ coefficient of $$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &=
\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{4\pi^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{9\pi^2}\right)\cdots
\end{align*}$$
can be proven inductively to be
$$-\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2}+\frac{1}{9\pi^2}\cdots\right)$$

I do not see any way of proving this by induction. I haven't ever come across this use of induction before actually. Could someone point me in the right direction of how to prove this using induction? I don't even know what the inductive hypothesis would be.

I can see this will certainly be the case though as the only way to have $x^2$ terms is by having each $x^2$ term in each bracket only multiplied together by the $1$'s inside the other brackets.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would start by proving using induction $$(1-x^2/\pi^2)(1-x^2/4\pi^2)...(1-x^2/n\pi^2)=-(1/\pi^2+1/4\pi^2..+1/n\pi^2)$$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I see, thanks. But does induction extend to the the case when  $n$ is infinity?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore eg see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98093/why-doesnt-induction-extend-to-infinity-re-fourier-series#:~:text=Mathematical%20induction%20affords%2C%20more%20than,is%20distinguished%20from%20the%20infinite.&text=But%20even%20then%2C%20induction%20on,of%20continuous%20functions%20is%20continuous.

Comment: @Alevel learner  in this case i  really dont see why induction wouldnt work /directly imply the result( i may be wrong).By the way this is a nice result!

Comment: In this case induction actually shows that ALL "partial products" works, which is exactly what "..." means in this case. The meaning of "..." is pretty nuanced in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a footnote in the Wikipedia page, did you read it?
It's a formula for the coefficient of $x^2$ of the partial product. That's what can be proved by induction

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your observation, I didn't notice that. I'll try doing that then.